# More help using numpy normal distributions

Tags: python, random, numpy, noise

I'm trying to add normally distributed amounts of noise, but it's acting strangely. When I input 1 standard deviation, it instead gives me a HUGE amount of extra noise. Perhaps you know the fix?

```
#irrelevant code precedes this
poisson = float((raw_input("Noise standard deviation: ")))
for i in range(0,len(ra_new)):
    ra_new2=cat['ra'][z2&lmass2&ra2&dec2][i]
    dec_new2=cat['dec'][z2&lmass2&ra2&dec2][i]
    id_new=cat['id'][z2&lmass2&ra2&dec2][i]
    target_pixel_x = ((ra_new2-ra_ref)/(pixel_size_x))+reference_pixel_x       
    target_pixel_y = ((dec_new2-dec_ref)/(pixel_size_y))+reference_pixel_y   
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5.,5.))
    timage=img[target_pixel_y-65:target_pixel_y+65,target_pixel_x-65:target_pixel_x+65]
    plt.imshow(img[target_pixel_y-65:target_pixel_y+65,target_pixel_x-65:target_pixel_x+65], vmin=-0.01, vmax=0.1, cmap='Greys')
    pf.writeto(t+'PHOTO'+s+str(i)+'.fits',timage,clobber=True,header=hdr)
    lmass3=cat['lmass'][z2&lmass2&ra2&dec2][i]
    print id_new, ra_new2,dec_new2

    name = t+'PHOTO'+s+str(i)+'.fits'

    im = pf.open(name)
    im0 = im[0]
    poissonNoise = np.random.normal(0,poisson, im0.data.shape).astype(float)
    test = im0.data + poissonNoise
    im0.data = test
    stringee = 'NOISE'
    pf.writeto(stringee+str(poisson)+name, data=test, clobber=True, header=im0.header)
print poisson
```

I get WAY more than 1 standard deviation of nose :-(

Comment: I don't want to be rude but [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is out there for a reason. It is really hard to read code like this. Also naming data from normal distribution `poissonNoise` is a little bit confusing ;)

Comment: Debug and inspect the values of `im` and `poissonNoise` before you add them up.

Comment: Are you viewing the output image to make an assessment? If so, then I bet the problem is the dynamic range of the output image is not what you expect, e.g. [0, 1] versus {0, 1, ..., 255}. But without knowing what `pf` is, it's difficult to tell.

Comment: `pf` is probably some package for dealing with `.fits` files.

Comment: 'pf' is what I renamed Pyfits to be. 

Thanks for the suggestions guys, I'll try all of it out.